Proof verification about Irreducible spaces
Motivation: I was doing some problems and this solution didn't feel satisfying, is there some error? Thank You
Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that $X$ is irreducible if it cannot be written as union of two closed proper subspaces.

Question: Show that being irreducible is equivalent to the fact that the intersection of any two nonempty open subsets $U, V \subset X$ is nonempty.

Proof attempt:
Subgoal 1: Irreducible implies This
Suppose I can find two none empty open subspaces, $U$ and $V$ whose intersection is empty,
That that they are disjoint. Claim: $X-U$ and $X-V$ are closed.  This follows from the fact that that the complement of any open proper subset is closed. Claim: $X-U, X-V$ are proper closed subspaces s.t. $X-U\cup X-V=X$. This is evidently true. Therefore X is reducible. By the contrapositive law QED.
Subgoal 2: This implies irreducible:
Suppose a space is reducible, call the two proper closed subset $A, B$.
claim the interior of $A$, and the interior of $X-A$ satisfy the property that their intersection is empty    and they are open. This follows  evidently from the definitions.

There is an error in Subgoal 2. You claim that interior of $A$ and $X \setminus A$ are nonempty. This is true only for the second one: $X \setminus A$ is open, so its interior is itself. It is nonempty because $A$ was proper. But we don't know anything about interior of $A$ itself; it might be empty.
This can be fixed by taking $X \setminus A$ and $X \setminus B$, which are both non-empty.
I would really recommend not splitting the task into 2 subgoals, since equivalence can be showed directly: just writing it down, we have that irreducible means
$$\forall A, B \subset X\,\text{ closed}\quad A \cup B \neq X$$
and your condition means
$$ \forall C, D \neq \emptyset \,\text{ open}\quad C \cap D \neq \emptyset.
$$
Those are the same when we replace sets by their complements, since $Y \neq X \iff X \setminus Y \neq \emptyset$.
(Here I want $\subset$ symbol to mean proper subset)
